# Mime type error after replace video src with jquery on client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I am trying to create video preview based on attached file url from local disk. Video Preview is opened in Bootstrap modal when user click on preview button. Here is the script of Attach video preview from local disk (its working fine):

```
video.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
$("#vid").html('<source src="'+video.src+'" type="video/mp4"> </source>');
$("#vid").load();
```

**Below is Jquery code of replacing video src with jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var vidsel = $("#vid source").attr('src');
    var vidreplace = $("#vidpr source").attr('src',vidsel);
    $("#vidpr").load();
 })   
});
```

**HTML CODE OF ATTACH FILE AND SHOW PREVIEW FROM LOCAL DISK- ITS WORKING FINE**
Note: $info[0]->ad_video is the src link of mp4 file that i already available on server.

```
<video  width="250px;" controls id="vid">
 <source src="<?php echo $info[0]->ad_video;?>" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video><hr/>
<center><b>REPLACE VIDEO IN .MP4 FORMAT</b><input type="file"  id="fileUp" name="fileUpload" onchange="setFileInfo(this.files)" accept="video/*">
```

**HTML CODE HTML OF WHERE I REPLACE THE VIDEO SOURCE FROM THE ATTACHED PREVIEW - URL REPLACED BUT SHOWS MIME TYPE NOT FOUND ERROR**

```
<video controls width="100%" id="vidpr">
       <source src="<?php echo $info[0]->ad_video;?>" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

Preview Button (Modal opener)

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="button">PREVIEW</button>
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE: Video replaced but HTML seems like this**

```
<video controls="" id="vidpr" width="100%">
       <source src="blob:http://example.com/21d353ed-8822-49f4-8e38-f881666aef27" type="video/mp4"></source>
    </video>
```

Please help Me! Thanks in Advance

Comment: What server is this running on? Apache? IIS? Sounds like the MIME type is not setup on the webserver.

Comment: Apache - LINUX, But my uploaded videos are running fine

Comment: Is MP4 in your htaccess?

Comment: Can you please check video.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]); i think it should be decrypt when i replace url and reload it in preview ?

Comment: Yes, zer00ne its added in .htaccess, all uploaded files are running fine

Comment: This is My .htaccess {AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/webm .webm}